# TCP Server with distants clients

Tags: javascript, php, sockets, tcp, network-programming

I need to define a way to achieve the following:

[image: TCP Diagram]

-Users will be browsing a Web Page on a terminal (with buttons, fields, etc...)

-There will be several of these terminals at different places (not in the same local network)

-When users interact with these terminals, orders will be sent to a TCP Server

-According to the terminal that is responsible of the order, TCP Server must send a command to the corresponding TCP Client on the other side.

-The terminals receiving data on the other side are Android terminal configured as TCP Client (part already developped and working in another configuration)

The goal is to avoid polling the server from each terminal to know if they must execute something.

My Question:

What would be the best structural approach to achieve this?

I tried to look at these solutions:

-Pure PHP TCP Server/Client developpment.

-JS with Node JS but i can't figure out how to make it work with HTML pages

In any case, what would be the way to have an 'Ever' listening TCP Server ready to listen to clients and send data to them? If i open my web pages on several terminals and create the socket again, it will replace the previously created one?

I really lack a lot of things regarding this domain and would appreciate leadings (no full solutions required as i always try to learn by myself).

Comment: Have you tried just doing it (using your favourite language)? What happened when you tried - what did you get stuck on? "Ever-listening" is the *normal* kind of TCP server - you don't have to do special work to make it "ever-listening"

Comment: Sounds like a use case for a message queue with push capabilities. Or something like websockets. Don't re-invent the wheel.

Comment: I'm really convinced that Socket/TCP is the solution, as my title suggests it. Not trying to re-invent anything.
My problem is mainly structural and in the way of doing things.
When i say "ever listening", i mean: the socket is always opened even if nobody launched the web page. If i open a socket each time a user navigate, wouldn't it replace the already opened one? Not sure if i'm making it clear here...

Comment: But the things I've mentioned all use raw TCP sockets under the hood. But they then build on that with established messaging protocols, security etc, all of which you would need to build yourself if you don't re-use an existing technology. Tcp is just a transport mechanism...you need protocols on top of that, and people have already solved that in various different ways. For context/concepts, have a look at https://www.imperva.com/learn/application-security/osi-model/,  especially the diagrams

Comment: `If i open a socket each time a user navigate, wouldn't it replace the already opened one`...well you'd only be re-opening a connection to an existing server potentially. If you're referring to my websockets suggestion, a websocket server runs independently of any browser. Nor does the connecting client need to be a browser, in fact. That's what it was designed for originally but it's expanded beyond that. Make sure you understand enough about a technology so you can be sure you can definitely dismiss it from your list or not! :-)

Comment: Yes i concede i lack some understanding about servers. I'm more used to mobile development. The server runs independently of any browser, that's an important point. So If i decided to use PHP to start my server, how would i, in the facts, start it? Definitly not with a browser. With a command on my admin console?

Comment: A server would normally run as a Service (or "daemon", on Linux) - i.e. an always-running process which is initiated by the operating system when the system starts up. So if the server was written in PHP (which I wouldn't particular recommend, since it's very poor at multithreading etc) you'd tell the operating system which PHP command to run at startup, and there would be something to keep it running, or restart it if it fails. "Ratchet" is a PHP websocket server which shows examples of this in its documentation.

Comment: Will definitely use NodeJS with Socket IO. Far more versatile than PHP. Now i need to find a Web Host that can handle it

Comment: You might find some cloud infrastructure is more flexible than traditional hosting, but I could be wrong. P.S. Another very solid technology option in the websocket space is ASP.NET with SignalR (you can even integrate SignalR with other non-.NET stuff too, I believe).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at technologies like **Socket.IO** or **gRPC**.

**REST API** will work generating a request, sending the request to the server and waiting for an answer.
Let's say that the server is passive and waiting for requests to answer.

With **Socket.IO** for example, there is a **link** between **client** and **server** and server can notify the client.